# How do you separate 6 articles into 2 columns in Joomla 3.x?

Tags: web, joomla, joomla3.0

I have 6 articles created for my Joomla page, but can't seem to figure out how to divide them into two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Three in each column. Ba dum tisch

Answer (score 0):

Create Menu with featured Article.Here, Go to Layout setting

```
1. Leading Articles set to 0
2. Intro Articles set to 6
3. Columns set to 2
```

Now you can see 2 columns